# login creation also creates a default user in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

When a login is created in sql server to connect to it, does it also creates a default user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a server login, like:

```
CREATE LOGIN TestUser WITH PASSWORD=N'password', DEFAULT_DATABASE=master
```

It will not create a database user, not even in the default database.  However, the login can access any database that has the `guest` user enabled.